# Indexpath.item resets after 2

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm having a problem when powering the data for the collection view inside a collection view..I guess I'm not doing it right. I'm taking the indexpath.item from data source delagate of the first collection view to power the data in the collection view inside cells of the first collection view. Index is ok up to third cell of the first collection view but then the text resets to Monday. Is there any way around this?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: StickersCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StickersCell

        switch indexPath.item {
        case 0:
            indexDan = 0
            print(indexPath.item)
        case 1:
            indexDan = 1
            print(indexPath.item)
        case 2:
            indexDan = 2
            print(indexPath.item)
        case 3:
            indexDan = 3
            print(indexPath.item)
        case 4:
            indexDan = 4
            print(indexPath.item)
        case 5:
            indexDan = 5
            print(indexPath.item)
        default:
            indexDan = 6
            print(indexPath.item)
        }
```

and the second collection view, where i want to have some labels displayed:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! kartica


        if indexDan == 0 {
            cell.labelMenu.text = "Monday"
        }else if indexDan == 1 {
            cell.labelMenu.text = "Tuesday"
        }else if indexDan == 2 {
            cell.labelMenu.text = "Wednesday"
        }else if indexDan == 3 {
            cell.labelMenu.text = "Thursday"
        }else if indexDan == 4 {
            cell.labelMenu.text = "Friday"
        }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `cellForItemAt` is called multiple times, once for each row, so when the table view is reloaded `indexDan` gets overwritten until the index of the last call of `cellForRow`

Comment: try to call collectionView -2- reloadData after changing indexDan